# Error in Update JPA Query

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem with this query when run is as follows

```
Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE Equipo c JOIN c.histAsociados e SET e.horasTrabajadas = (CAST(c.horastd AS DECIMAL(18,2)) - (c.horastotales AS DECIMAL(18,2))) WHERE c.id=" + equipo.getId());
```

This is the exception that gets thrown when running

```
  The SET identifier is missing from the UPDATE clause.  [39, 39] The equal sign must be specified.[16, 38]  The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar.[40, 43] The identification variable 'SET' cannot be a reserved word.[115, 115] The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression.[115, 115] The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression.[116, 126]  The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar.[133, 151] The query contains a malformed ending.
```

Comment: Read the JPA spec on JPQL syntax. Yours is wrong, as the message says. JPQL != SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, putting it into a subquery, assuming that histAsociados is an entity inside Equipo entity:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE Equipo c SET c.histAsociados WHERE c.histAsociados.id in(select Equipo.id from Equipo c1 LEFT JOIN c1.histAsociados e WHERE e.horasTrabajadas = (CAST(c1.horastd AS DECIMAL(18,2)) - (c1.horastotales AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AND c1.histAsociados.id = e.id) AND c.id=:id).setParameter("id", equipo.getId())
```

Also, could you please try putting some simple names to the attributes of entities. That increases readability.

Comment: hi thanks for help me im write this query so launch error.

Comment: hi friend im try your query and launch this error [36, 36] The equal sign must be specified.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JPA specification, your syntax cannot be correct. The simplified form of the syntax for the `UPDATE`statement can be stated as follows:

> UPDATE <entity_name> <identification_variable> SET <identification_variable>.<state_field> = <value> WHERE <condition>

Applying this for your case it might look like:

```
"UPDATE HistAsociado?? e SET e.horasTrabajadas = (SELECT (CAST(c.horastd AS DECIMAL(18,2)) - CAST(c.horastotales AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS DIFF FROM Equipo c WHERE c.id= " + equipo.getId())
```

In the above statement, I was **guessing** that `HistAsociado` could be an Entity name; otherwise you have to correct it!

The result of the subquery must also be a single value.

**Warning:** The modified statement would update **all** the records in the table as there is no **WHERE** condition is specified.

So, use this as a hint to solve the problem and don't use it before you have corrected the **guessing** and added the **WHERE** condition.

For more information and examples, you could read [JPA update statement](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_bulk_ops) and [this one too](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/update).